# Route [blog.all_article] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I want to go from `home.blade.php` to `all_article.blade.php`, but they tell me that such a route was not found. What am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

blog/home.blade

```
 <a href="{{route('blog.all_article')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Add</a>
```

BlogController

```
public function articlesAll_blade(){
   return view('blog.all_article',[
     'articles' => Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10),
      'footers' => System::all(),
   ]);
}
```

web.php

```
 Route::get('/', 'BlogController@articlesAll', function () {
     return view('blog.home');
 });

 Route::get('/all_article', 'BlogController@articlesAll_blade', function () {
     return view('blog.all_article');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are missing is a route name, add a name to your route

```
Route::get('/all_article', 'BlogController@articlesAll_blade', function () {
     return view('blog.all_article');
 })->name('blog.all_article');// see the name part
```

doc link https://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('/all_article','BlogController@articlesAll_blade')->name('blog.all_article');
```